# How to set texture with camera view

Tags: texturing, camera

With add image as plane i have add an image and in the texture coordinates i have set to camera. I want my image to be set in camera. In the view port it look set but when preview render the image gets smaller. How to set a background image with the camera. Any other alternative or something going wrong with my nodes. I dont want to scale or rate with the texture coordinates. as in the 3d view i can see it. Any suggestion or help how it works

[image]

[image]

When i rotate the camera with the background set. It small and get bigger and disappear. But not in the camera view.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tUNi.jpg

Comment: Have considered the Compositor? You render your foreground with transparency then overlay the result on to your image.

Answer (score 0):

the textured view ignores texture coordinates. just set the first node back to UV and it should work just fine.

Comment: Plz check the question section below part.